# Определить идентификатор с помощью директивы - т.е определить своё число в define?

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем заключается проверка существования идентификатора?

Comment: Может директива ifdef имеется в виду?

Comment: скорей всего `#ifndef` и `#error`, но лучше спросить у того, кто это задание дал...

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю ещё откуда мне x нужно брать

Comment: Просто определить его в define своим каким-то числом?

Comment: @Silverone, скорей всего, но опять же вопрос не к нам...

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef x
#define x 5
#endif
```

Вот так что ли?

Comment: насколько я понял должно быть не определение x если не существует, а поднятие ошыбки